# Save OpenAI streaming response after finishing stream

Tags: python, django, orm, openai-api

I have a Django API that streams responses from OpenAI.

But I wan't to save the final response in my database after finishing.

My code for streaming is something like this:

```py
def create_chat_message_and_stream_response_from_ai(
    message: str,
):
    def stream():
        final_answer = ""

        data_queue = ChatService().get_stream_queue(
            new_message=message,
        )

        while True:
            data = data_queue.get()

            if data == "CLOSE":
                ChatMessage.objects.create(
                    message=final_answer,
                    agent="ai",
                )

                break

            final_answer += data
            yield data

    response = StreamingHttpResponse(stream())
    response["Content-Type"] = "text/event-stream"
    return response
```

but when I create the ChatMessage object, it raises

`django.core.exceptions.SynchronousOnlyOperation: You cannot call this from an async context - use a thread or sync_to_async.`

I tried to add `sync_to_async` wrapper but now I have this error:

`RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'SyncToAsync.__call__' was never awaited sync_to_async(ChatMessage.objects.create)( RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback`